# Java Concurrency in practice "Listing 12.5. Producer-consumer test program for BoundedBuffer.", per-thread checksum?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* and encounter the following code snippet.

```
// Listing 12.5. Producer-consumer test program for BoundedBuffer. I merge several "Listing"s and add some `printf` statements.

import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class PutTakeTest {
    private static final ExecutorService pool
            = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final AtomicInteger putSum = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final AtomicInteger takeSum = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final CyclicBarrier barrier;
    private final BoundedBuffer<Integer> bb;
    private final int nTrials, nPairs;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PutTakeTest(10, 10, 100000).test(); // sample parameters
        pool.shutdown();
    }

    PutTakeTest(int capacity, int npairs, int ntrials) {
        this.bb = new BoundedBuffer<Integer>(capacity);
        this.nTrials = ntrials;
        this.nPairs = npairs;
        this.barrier = new CyclicBarrier(npairs * 2 + 1);
    }

    void test() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < nPairs; i++) {
                pool.execute(new Producer());
                pool.execute(new Consumer());
            }
            barrier.await(); // wait for all threads to be ready
            barrier.await(); // wait for all threads to finish
            System.out.printf("putSum.get() == takeSum.get(): %b\n", putSum.get() == takeSum.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    class Producer implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.printf("currentThread: %s, putSum: %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), putSum.hashCode());
                int seed = (this.hashCode() ^ (int) System.nanoTime());
                int sum = 0;
                barrier.await();
                for (int i = nTrials; i > 0; --i) {
                    bb.put(seed);
                    sum += seed;
                    seed = xorShift(seed);
                }
                putSum.getAndAdd(sum);
                barrier.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        private int xorShift(int y) {
            y ^= (y << 6);
            y ^= (y >>> 21);
            y ^= (y << 7);
            return y;
        }
    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.printf("currentThread: %s, takeSum: %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), takeSum.hashCode());
                barrier.await();
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = nTrials; i > 0; --i) {
                    sum += bb.take();
                }
                takeSum.getAndAdd(sum);
                barrier.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It then says:

> PutTakeTest in Listings 12.5 and 12.6 starts N producer threads that generate elements and enqueue them, and N consumer threads that dequeue them. Each thread updates the checksum of the elements as they go in or out, using a **per-thread checksum** that is combined at the end of the test run so as to add no more synchronization or contention than required to test the buffer.

Per-thread checksum? We only create one single `PutTakeTest` instance and its member variable **`putSum` and `takeSum` is shared among threads**. Is this an error?

```
// output

currentThread: pool-1-thread-1, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-20, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-19, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-18, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-17, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-16, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-15, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-14, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-13, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-12, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-11, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-10, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-9, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-8, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-7, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-6, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-5, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-4, takeSum: 1616922032
currentThread: pool-1-thread-3, putSum: 1211857397
currentThread: pool-1-thread-2, takeSum: 1616922032
putSum.get() == takeSum.get(): true
```

Comment: ? `AtomicInteger putSum = new AtomicInteger(0);` You know what AtomicInteger does, right?

Comment: I know, but it is not one `putSum` per thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The per-thread checksum is `int sum`. Each of these is combined into `putSum` or `takeSum` at the end.

Comment: I have thought about it, but I think per-task checksum would be a better name because you create a new `sum` in every `run`. The reason why it is per-thread is that we use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and the number of tasks is not greater than the maximum size of thread pool. Do I understand it right?

Comment: The `sum` is a local variable.  It's always local per thread.  There's no contention here.